# Select point features using spatial query

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I have two postgres tables, one polygon features and second point features, having same projection. 
What i want to do is to select only the points which contains in large polygon and does not contain in the small polygons, as highlighted in the picture below , using spatial query.

[image]

I am trying to do with the below query is to, `select` all the points which does not intersect/contain in the small polygon (`kind=1`) and then return those points from the selected features which contains in the large polygon (`kind=2`).
The query results in to `0 rows`.

```
select 
      *
 from 
    (
     select p.geom as point_geom,sp.geom as polygon_geom
     from polygons sp, points p
     where st_disjoint(sp.polygon_geom,p.point_geom) and sp.kind = 1
    ) as subquery
 where st_contains(subquery.scale_geom,subquery.pois_geom) and subquery.kind = 2;
```

The `kind` column in the above query is used to differentiate between these polygons, where `kind = 1` represents the small polygon and `kind = 2` the large polygon. Also both polygons overlaps which means the points contain in small polygon also contains in large polygon.

**Update**

After running this query:

`SELECT DISTINCT p.geom as point_geom
FROM points p 
     JOIN polygons poly1 ON ST_Disjoint(p.geom, poly1.geom)
     JOIN polygons poly2 ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, poly2.geom)
WHERE 
     poly1.kind = 1 AND poly2.kind = 2
;`

Some results were not acceptable like:

[image]

The encircled points should be only in kind 1 but they are selected.

Comment: Your subquery only returns those polygons with `kind = 1`. And then in the outer query, you ask for `kind = 2`. The result is naturally empty.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Do you first need to select the small (`kind=1`) polygons inside every large (`kind=2`) polygon or is the condition more relaxed, i.e you want every point that is inside at least one `kind=2` polygon, but not inside any `kind=1` polygon?

Comment: @dhke yes i want to select every point which is atleast inside one 'kind = 2' polygon but not inside any 'kind = 1' polygons

Comment: As you said `the result is naturally empty` How can i fix this?

Comment: This question is incomplete. what does your table look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you've got two orthogonal conditions:

1. All points that are disjoint with `kind = 1` polygons
2. All points that intersect with `kind = 2` polygons

and you need the intersection thereof. A double-join should do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.geom as point_geom
FROM points p 
     JOIN polygons poly1 ON ST_Disjoint(p.geom, poly1.geom)
     JOIN polygons poly2 ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, poly2.geom)
WHERE 
     poly1.kind = 1 AND poly2.kind = 2
;
```

should yield the expected result. The `DISTINCT` is only necessary if a point is potentially contained in multiple polygons. Don't forget to put indexes on `polygons.geom`, `points.geom`, and `polygons.kind`, because otherwise this will be horribly slow (`EXPLAIN` shows two nested loops).

Comment: See the updated question. At least your query gave me some results, Thanks to you, but there is still some problem

Comment: Interesting, have you tried querying for all `kind = 2` polygons the affected points intersect with?

Comment: according to my data, `kind 1` intersects with `1289` points and `kind 2` intersects with `174485` points which means the above query should result in about `173196` points but i got `161898` points instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.geom AS point_geom, big.geom AS polygon_geom
FROM points p 
JOIN polygons big ON ST_Intersects(big.geom, p.geom) AND big.kind = 1
JOIN polygons small ON (NOT ST_Intersects(small.geom, p.geom)) AND small.kind = 2;
```

This query reads something like: "select all points that intersect the big polygons, but exclude any points that intersect with a small polygon".

You should avoid using `ST_Disjoint()` because it does not use indexes.